# Java8 Stream how to groupingBy and combine elements with same fields

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

- I hava an order list that contains different id and date.
- Now, I need to combine order amount of same id and date.

The core of this problem maybe is how to create a Collector that counld combine Orders with same id and date, and the result is an Order list rather than a Map<Integer, List>.

Is there any other ways to simplify this flow?

```
public class Order {
    private Integer id;
    private LocalDate date;
    private double amount;
    public void accept(Order other) {
        setId(other.getId());
        setDate(other.getDate());
        setAmount(getAmount() + other.getAmount());
    }
    public Order combine(Order other) {
        setId(other.getId());
        setDate(other.getDate());
        setAmount(getAmount() + other.getAmount());
        return this;
    }
}
```

```
    List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Order> orders = mockData();
    Map<Integer, List<Order>> collect = list.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Order::getId));

    collect.forEach((id, orders) -> {
        Map<LocalDate, Order> resultMap = orders.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Order::getDate, mapping(order -> order, Collector.of(Order::new, Order::accept, Order::combine))));
        result.addAll(resultMap.values());
    });
```

Comment: Why would orders have the "same ID"? IDs should be unique

Comment: What’s the point of wrapping a collector in `mapping(order -> order, …)`? There’s also no need for the `accept` method, as you can use the `Order::combine` instead of `Order::accept`.

Answer (score 3):

I would first make a new record so that you can work with id and date at once.

```
record IdAndDate(Integer id, LocalDate date) {}
```

To not get a `List<Order>` as the map's value type, use the `toMap` collector. You can then specify a "merge function". That is where you specify `Order::combine`.

```
var result = new ArrayList<>(
    orders.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            x -> new IdAndDate(x.getId(), x.getDate()), // key mapper
            Function.identity(), // value mapper (no change)
            Order::combine // merge function
        )
    ).values()
);
```

Note that `Order.combine` changes the instance on which it is called, which means that some of the orders in the original list would be changed by this operation. This is also true for your original code, so I'll assume this fact doesn't matter in your case. Just in case you don't want that to happen, you should make `combine` return a new instance of `Order`, instead of `this`.

Comment: …and when you’re on an older Java version without `record`, you can use `x -> Arrays.asList(x.getId(), x.getDate())` instead of `x -> new IdAndDate(x.getId(), x.getDate())`. It’s worth noting that the solution modifies some of the existing `Order` objects (just like the original code).

Comment: @Holger Thanks for pointing that out. I felt like I forgot something too :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also nest the groupingBy calls and do it like:

```
List<Order> orders = mockData();

List<Order> result = orders.stream()   // Stream<Order>
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getId,
                                      Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getDate)))   //Map<Integer, Map<LocalDate,List<Order>>>
                          .values()   //Collection<Map<LocalDate,List<Order>>>
                          .stream()    ////Stream<Map<LocalDate,List<Order>>>
                          .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())    //Stream<List<Order>>
                          .map(list -> list.stream().reduce(Order::combine).get())     // Stream<Order>
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi Eritrean, I dont quite understand this part `.flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
                          .map(list -> list.stream().reduce(Order::combine).get())`. Could you explain what it is doing here? It looks like you are extracting the nested Map and getting its values? Is streaming it necessary?

Comment: You should not use `reduce` with `Order::combine`, as this function modifies one of its inputs.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X The nested groupingBy produces a xxx. Since the OP wants to merge the orders that have the same id and belong to the same tag, I first stream over the values of the outer map and reduce the values of the inner map for the respective day. See my edit, hope it is clearer with the type of the stream after each step.

Comment: @Holger I thought that was the intention of OP. What do you recomend instead of `reduce` ?

Comment: The simplest approach is to use a Collector producing the intended result in the first place, instead of first collecting into a `List` and then perform another Stream operation on the list. Just like the OP already did. This still bears the problematic design of modifying the incoming objects, but it least, it doesn’t clash with the concept of *Reduction*. (And it’s more efficient than producing intermediate lists)